# How do I register default interfaces with Castle Windsor given an interface ancestor?

Tags: castle-windsor-3

I have the following:

```
interface IAncestor { }

interface IDescendant1 : IAncestor { }

interface IDescendant2 : IAncestor { } 

class Descendant1 : IDescendant1 { }

class Descendant2 : IDescendant2 { }
```

What I would like to be able to do is automatically have Castle Windsor find all `IDescendantX`-`DescendantX` pairs without me having to specify them manually. Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IAncestor>()
            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient()
        );
```

but this does not find the default interfaces. (I'm having trouble phrasing my question with the right terminology, so could not find a topic on SO that already answers this, sorry if it's a duplicate...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the problem here is lack of access modifiers.  If you add IncludeNonPublicTypes() the following test passes:

```
[Test]
public void Test() 
{        
    //Arrange
    WindsorContainer sut = new WindsorContainer();

    //Act
    sut.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
            .BasedOn<IAncestor>()
            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());

    //Assert
    Assert.That(sut.Resolve<IDescendant1>(), Is.InstanceOf<Descendant1>());
    Assert.That(sut.Resolve<IDescendant2>(), Is.InstanceOf<Descendant2>());
}
```